# Playing audio from stream with HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I've got problem with playing audio from stream in web browser. I am streaming voice via [BinaryJS](http://binaryjs.com/) as 2048-length Int16 arrays to client's browser and I am getting very noisy output. This is how I am receiving the stream:

```
 var 
    client,
    audioContext,
    audioBuffer,
    sourceNode,
    sampleSize = 2048,

  function main() {
    try {
        audioContext = new AudioContext();
    } catch(e) {
        alert('Web Audio API is not supported in this browser');
    }
    sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    sourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

    connectClient();

    playSound();
  };

  function playSound() {

    sourceNode.start(0);    

  };

   function onError(e) {
    console.log('error' + e);
  };

  function connectClient() {
    client = new BinaryClient('ws://localhost:3000');
    client.on('open', function() {
      console.log('stream opened');

    });
    client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){
      stream.on('data', function(data){
        var integers = new Int16Array(data);
        var audioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(1, 2048, 4410);
        audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(integers);
        sourceNode.buffer = audioBuffer;
        });
      });
    };

  main();
```

What should I do to get clean audio?

Answer (score 1):

I think your playback technique here is causing the noise – first of all, can you ensure that your `stream` event fires often enough to provide continuous data for Web Audio? If it doesn't, then the noise you hear is the pops and clicks after each bit of audio stops playing. Also, updating the data by swapping ArrayBuffers on `sourceNode` isn't a good idea.

I would suggest using a [ScriptProcessorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode) with your desired buffer size – this gives you the ability to insert raw data into the graph at audio rate, which should reduce the noise. Look at [this demo](http://mdn.github.io/script-processor-node/) to see how to set up the node, basically you just need to fill the `outputBuffer` with your stream data.

*This will only really help if your streaming is faster than the audio rate!*

Good luck,

jakub

Comment: Hi Jakub, thank you for your answer. Do you have any idea how to buffer those 2048 data chunks and play them when it is enough to have good quality sound?

Comment: That depends largely on what the desired sound is. In general, you can create an Array of `Float32Array` (or `Int16` in your case) chunks, push to it whenever `stream` fires, and start shifting chunk by chunk when the array is long enough. You can keep checking the length to make sure you always are a couple of buffers ahead.

Since it's voice, you could potentially buffer each continuous phrase by looking at the RMS loudness of the signal. Here's a [library](http://github.com/hughrawlinson/meyda) that might help. (sorry for the self-promotion, I kind of co-wrote it :P)

Comment: Do let me know how it went! Would be interested in how BinaryJS aligns with this approach.